# Syntax errors when passing initializer list as function argument for vector in VS12

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vector

I have a function that takes in a vector as an input argument:

```
void expandVector(std::vector<int> inputVector, std::vector<int>& outputVector);
```

When I call this function, I typically only have 1 element in the input vector, so I pass in an initializer list with 1 element.

```
std::vector<int> expandedVector;
expandVector({1337}, expandedVector);
```

This works fine with `gcc 4.8.2` but I get these errors when I try to compile with Visual Studio 2012:

```
source.cpp(353) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ')' before '{'
source.cpp(353) : error C2660: 'expandVector' : function does not take 0 arguments
source.cpp(353) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
source.cpp(353) : error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '}'
source.cpp(353) : error C2059: syntax error : ')'
```

When I check the [MSDN documentation for `vector::vector`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzw4bwhd.aspx), it lists the constructor with initializer list, and furthermore, the example shows it being used.

```
vector<int> v8{ { 1, 2, 3, 4 } };
```

Even though I don't explicitly declare and name a vector (like `v8` in the example), shouldn't I still be able to pass in an initializer list to a function expecting a vector?

Comment: Does VS 2012 support initializer lists? Doesn't seem so.

Comment: Doh... I forgot to change my version to 2012 on the MSDN documentation. The [MSDN `vector::vector` page for VS2012](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzw4bwhd(v=vs.110).aspx) indeed does not have the constructor with the initializer list...

Comment: That's not what I meant. I mean the support for the language feature, that is, being able to initialize entities with `{` and `}`

Comment: @Columbo: true, but I would have seen that constructor wasn't available if I had the right version... I suppose I'll have to dumb down my code to Micro$oft level.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, thanks to Columbo for pointing me in the right direction.

Visual Studio 2012 doesn't support initializer lists, see [Support for C++11 Features (Modern C++)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx) on MSDN.

Also, the page for `vector::vector` I originally referred to is for VS 2013. When I picked the [correct VS 2012 version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zzw4bwhd(v=vs.110).aspx), I found that this constructor is not available.

The solution will be to replace

```
expandVector({1337}, expandedVector);
```

with

```
expandVector(std::vector<int>(1, 1337), expandedVector);
```

Comment: vs2013 is vs12, vs2012 is vs11 :P, and you should upgrade! i just upgraded recently for all the missing c++11 features